# Верстка мобильно приложения - name="viewport"

Tags: mobile, вёрстка

Всем привет! Возник вопрос с коллегами, который не можем решить. 
Известно, что при верстки мобильного приложения  нужно использовать

```
 name="viewport" content="width=device-width"
```

но тут же возник вопрос. можно же к примеру значение `content` устанавливать и фиксировано, скажем 640 пикселей и все масштабируется в зависимости от экрана или же оставить `width=device-width` и делать верстку резиновой ??

подскажите пожалуйста как сделать лучше!

спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**<meta name="viewport" content='width=640'>** - для сайта фиксированой ширины

**<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0,maximum-scale=1" />** - это для адаптивного сайта

Мое мнение лучше верстать сразу адаптивно

Comment: а если это не адаптивный сайт, а мобильно приложение - в плане на выходе для андроида например просто будет .apk  - имеет ли это разницу ? <meta name="viewport" content='width=640'> по идее это же просто масштабируется? и будет под те же смартфоны в 320 пикселей ширины - тоже уменьшено все пропорционально?

Comment: нет не пропорционально - появиться полоса прокрутки (если ширина сайта фиксированная)

Comment: просто пробовала с фиксированной шириной в 640 пикселей открывать на смартфоне с разрешением 320 - полосы нет, все смаштабировалось. вот и вопрос - зачем платить больше , если вроде и так ок

Comment: "maximum-scale=1" - почти всегда зло.